# Wrap a "variant" struct/union using SWIG

Tags: python, python-3.x, swig, variant

I'm trying to wrap a kind of "variant" type using SWIG. I mean something a bit like GType or alike, where the pointer you get is of a base type but the real type is actually much bigger and can be found out using a field in the base.

```c
#define OBJ_TYPE_1 1
#define OBJ_TYPE_2 2

typedef struct Base_t {
    DWORD mObjectSize;
    DWORD mObjectType;
} Base;

typedef struct Object1_t {
    Base mBase;
    DWORD member1;
    DWORD member2;
    // Some specific members...
} Object1;

typedef struct Object2_t {
    Base mBase;
    DWORD member3;
    DWORD member4;
     WORD member5;
    // Some different specific members ...
} Object2;
```

The proposed C interface uses the library in a way ressembling the following

```c
Base base;

// Get object header to find out type
PeekObject(&base);

// Treat object depending on type
if (base.mObjectType == OBJ_TYPE_1) {
    Object1* obj = (Object1*) malloc(sizeof(Object1));
    ReadObject(&(obj->mBase));
    DWORD blahblah = obj->member2;
}
else if (base.mObjectType == OBJ_TYPE_2) {
    // ...
}
```

How would you wrap this in SWIG? Ideally, in Python you would be able to just *"ReadObject"* and directly receive an object of the right type.

```py
>>> obj = lib.read_object()
>>> obj
<class 'lib.Object1'>
```

I cannot change the library, but I can modify the wrapping (.i file). Should I go with custom code? Should I use typemaps? I don't know why, I remember that there was specifically an example for this in SWIG's documentation, but I'm unable to find it again...

Comment: After trying Cython, which was also somewhat a nightmare, I used pure C Python API instead.